# Member Portals for Employees

Tags: categories, members, plugin, member-management, export

I have a client who is requesting a member portal. The concept  is to have two parts to this portal. Part one is from the Employer side. Employer logs-in  to access Employees resumes and information and can search by keyword or industry. Part Two is from the employee side. The employee logs-in and can update their information, add keywords, upload a photo and resume and have access to restricted content.

I'm not too familiar with member management in EE so my questions are this: 
1. Are there any plugins that could make this project run smoother such as User?
2. Is it possible to have a way that an employer can view the details of an employee, and download that data to a file? Would that require a plugin? 
3. Is there an advance search that I would need for this type of project?

thanks 
jeff

**Here is an update**
I now have the docs to begin and I want to make sure these are the right plugins to use on this project. I am think of using Zoo Visitor, Safe Cracker, Super Search and Grid Field. The idea behind the project is that there are two types of members, employers who want access to employees and employees who want access to employers. Both need to be able to update info and search for each other and both login to the site.

Answer (score 2):

think you're very lucky :) check this new post by Sean Smith on how he built a resume builder 
[Channel Form and Grid/Matrix fields](http://caffeinecreations.ca/blog/channel-form-and-grid-matrix-fields)

Answer (score 1):

Have built a few things like this in EE. Look at Zoo Visitor for the member registration and something like Low Search for the search side.

There are more than a few ways to go about it. Have a look on Devot-EE for more addons that could help your build.

Answer (score 1):

We're just about to a launch a full job portal site for a client that includes Employer access with ability to add/edit jobs, job applicants with ability to upload resume, save jobs to favorites and apply directly to jobs.

We used Zoo Visitor for our member management which was beyond easy and then utilized Reefine for the search filters. Freeforms was used for all the forms to communicate and LinkVault for secure handling of all resumes so that they aren't easily accessible via web (all files stored above root).

Hope that helps...let me know if you have other questions :)

Comment: Thank you for the information. I do have one question, if I have 2 groups (employers and employees) would you set those up as member categories? Each one has to lo-gin to get access to information on each. So employers can login and update information,  then have the ability to filter employees to find someone who might fit. Then the same goes the other way, employees can look for jobs posted by employers. Then filter them that way? Trying to wrap my head around where to begin, haven't done this in a while. I have Zoo Visitor installed now.

Answer (score 0):

Another add-on to consider for profiles management is Profile:Edit. And of course, Freemember.